# Create AWS VPC Endpoint for SQS

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-vpc

I have a couple of Lambda functions that require access to other services I have in AWS inside a VPC. So I have added these Lambda functions to the same VPC which makes them lose internet access.

One of the service I need access to is a SQS queue, which is not in the VPC as it doesn't support it.

I found two solutions to my problem:

- Create a NAT gateway and allow my function to access the internet
- Create a VPC endpoint for SQS

I wanted to go with the latter. When I did that, the Lambda worked fine, but I couldn't deploy new code to my Beanstalk instances. That should have nothing to do with it! I spent hours to realize Beanstalk uses SQS to send messages to my instances to perform the deploy.

Questions:

- Is it a better solution to use a VPC endpoint rather than a NAT gateway? (it seems to be cheaper)
- If so, how can I keep my Beanstalk instances working correctly?